# Not sure why this javascript isnt applying to my dynamically added elements when I am calling the event attaching function afterwards

Tags: javascript, html

the eventListener console log is not firing for some reason. I feel like the code structure should be working? I assume its something to do with javascript being asynchronous

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
if ($(".custom_1").length) {
    $(".custom_1").append(`
        <div class="slider-container">
            <input type="range" min="0" max="5" value="2" step="1" class="slider" id="mySlider">
            <div class="labels">
                <label for="0" class="label">0</label>
                <label for="1" class="label">1</label>
                <label for="2" class="label">2</label>
                <label for="3" class="label">3</label>
                <label for="4" class="label">4</label>
                <label for="5" class="label">5</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    `);

    initSlider(); // Initialize the custom slider after it's added to the DOM
}

function initSlider() {
    let slider = document.getElementById('mySlider');
    let labels = document.querySelectorAll('.label');
    
    slider.addEventListener('input', function() {
        console.log("slider changed")
        let value = parseInt(slider.value);
        labels.forEach(label => label.classList.remove('active'));
        labels[value].classList.add('active');
    });
}
```

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous here.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I know, so do you have any ideas of why the javascript isn't being attached to the elements?

Comment: Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ab2dq4o8/

Comment: @Barmar So it does. Thankyou for the help. The problem must be something to do with when I am calling the code then, its called in a hook when a page is loaded.

Comment: Is it adding the slider at all?

Comment: You are not using `label` correctly. The `for` attribute should have a value that matches the `id` attribute value of a form field of some kind. In your case, I don't see the reason for using `label` in the first place.